# Store WHERE IN condition / filter from query to a table postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a view to reduce query time over JSONB. To do this I want to create a table that keeps track of the `WHERE IN` condition of this exact query `SELECT data_timestamp, key, value FROM hit_count CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data) WHERE key IN ('2134','1234',...);` as it comes in. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: How is this being called, as part of a function/procedure?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock thats the question. I tried making a trigger on `INSERT ON pg_stat_activity` to no avail. If successful I was going to use a `LIKE` statement to `select` to find all queries that met the condition... but thats a no go... 

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a view on pg_stat_statement?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I have not. Im working this angle atm `CREATE FUNCTION test(VARIADIC arr text[]) RETURNS TABLE (data_time TIMESTAMPTZ, id text, data jsonb) AS 'SELECT data_timestamp, key, value FROM hit_count CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data) WHERE key = ALL ($1)' LANGUAGE SQL;` but for unknown reasons `key = ALL ($1)` is not accepting multiple inputs

Comment: @JonathanWillcock If I can get the above to work. Ill just insert the ids into a table